# How do I sync the history of my local and remote repository after squashing commits locally?

Tags: git

I've squashed commits on my local branch using `git rebase --interactive HEAD~N` and pushed the changes to my remote repository. However, now my commits are only squashed on my local repository. All 12 of the commits I squashed locally are still listed in the history of my remote branch. I believe this is because I didn't add the --force flag when I pushed it to remote, but now it is too late for that.

I've tried to make a new branch and push this branch to my remote repository, but the commits are still listed un-squashed.

So how can I sync the history of my local branch with that of the remote branch?

Comment: Something is missing here: After the interactive rebase to your local branch, you should not have been able to push to the remote without doing a force push.  Please add all the steps you have taken here.

Answer (score 1):

Is it too late? When I try to push after rebase without force I will get a message that push was rejected. You should be able to add --force and push it successfully

Comment: I can confirm that it successfully pushed to remote without --force. Doing a --force push now returns the message "Everything up-to-date"

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Using `--force` will cause problems, especially if you are working with a team.

Everyone's pushes will be rejected after that, plus you may even push over someone else's work!

Also, if you are using a CI pipeline you may break things.

That being said, if you are absolutely certain you will not cause any issues (working alone, no multiple development machines, no deploy pipelines), just do a `git push --force` and you will be fine.

For future reference, it is a good practice to use a development branch for each feature/fix/whatever and only merge to master when you are all done (cleaned up, committed and squashed).